# Python-like dictionary declaration for C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, dictionary, syntactic-sugar

In Python one can do:

```
d = {1 : 'Hello', 2 : 'World'}
```

In C# it's more verbose:

```
Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1, 'Hello');
d.Add(2, 'World');
```

How can I make this less verbose?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the [collection initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) (and [implicit typing with `var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)):

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1, "Hello"}, {2, "World"} };
```

This code will actually be compiled down to the code you have above. Note that you (unfortunately) can't elide the constructor or the generic type arguments.

Not quite Pythonic, but getting there!